# st.file_uploader returns None

Tags: streamlit

```py
import streamlit as st 
import PIL as pil 


st.title("Dogs and Cats")


upload_button = st.button("Upload Image")

if upload_button:
    image_file = st.file_uploader("Upload image", type=["jpg","jpeg"])

    if image_file is not None:
        org_image = pil.Image.open(image_file, mode='r')
        st.text("Uploaded image")
        st.image(org_image, caption='Image for Prediction')
        pred_button = st.button("Perform Prediction")
        if pred_button:
            st.image(org_image, caption='Predicted Image')
            st.write("The class is : ")
```

In this code, after file is uploaded it returns `None` to `image_file`.
This problem didn't occur when used without

```py
upload_button = st.button("Upload Image")
if upload_button:
```

I am using streamlit version 1.14, python 3.8.10

Comment: Streamlit button is designed like that. After pressing it, SRCTB - Streamlit Reruns the Code from TOP to Bottom. It remembers the value of the button. But if you change another widget value like pressing the upload button, SRCTB, and forgets the last value of the button. The variable assigned to the button is now false. So the code after `upload_button` will not be executed. If you really need a button, you can use the code suggested by Jamiu. Or even a checkbox will do. If not just use the upload widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streamlit button has no callback that is why you are having that problem. User entry disappears when you try to perform an operation under a button because the page reruns. To handle such problem you should initialize a session state for your `upload_button`.

```py
import streamlit as st
import PIL as pil

st.title("Dogs and Cats")

uploadbtn = st.button("Upload Image")

if "uploadbtn_state" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.uploadbtn_state = False

if uploadbtn or st.session_state.uploadbtn_state:
    st.session_state.uploadbtn_state = True

    image_file = st.file_uploader("Upload image", type=["jpg", "jpeg"])

    if image_file is not None:
        org_image = pil.Image.open(image_file, mode='r')
        st.text("Uploaded image")
        st.image(org_image, caption='Image for Prediction')
        pred_button = st.button("Perform Prediction")
        if pred_button:
            st.image(org_image, caption='Predicted Image')
            st.write("The class is : ")
```

output:
[image]