# A widget disappers when a button is clicked twice in streamlit in Python

Tags: python, html, button, widget, streamlit

## What I want to achieve

To show a widget only when a button is clicked in streamlit. The return value of a time-consuming operation will be loaded to the widget. While the operation is being done, the button is disabled. Every time the button is clicked, the new value of the operation will be loaded to it.

## Issue

When the button is clicked once, the widget is shown. However, when the button is clicked again, it disappers. It looks like the entire webpage was reset. When the button is clicked one more time, the widget is shown again. The series of events are cycling.

## Environment

- Windows 8.1
- Python 3.9.13
- streamlit 1.20.0

## Minimal reproducible example

```
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as stc

def very_heavy_operation():
    return 'result'

def main():
    process_btn_ph = st.empty()
    process_btn = process_btn_ph.button('process', disabled=False, key='1')
    text_wait = st.empty()

    print(process_btn) # for debug
    if process_btn:
        process_btn_ph.button('process', disabled=True, key='2')
        text_wait.markdown('**processing...**')
        result = very_heavy_operation()

        stc.html(f'<div>{result}</div>', height=100, scrolling=True)

        process_btn_ph.button('process', disabled=False, key='3')
        text_wait.empty()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## What I tried

I googled "streamlit button placeholder push twice reset" but no useful information was found.

When the button is clicked once, `print(process_btn) # for debug` yields `True`. But when it is clicked again, it yields `False`. If the two `process_btn_ph.button()` in `if process_btn:` are removed, the code works as I want it to. I believe `process_btn_ph.button()` does something wrong but I have no idea how to solve it.

Any suggestions are greatly appeciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The post [Jamiu S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19290081/jamiu-s). suggested answered my question. Many thanks!
[st.file_uploader returns None](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74518601/4061339)

```
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as stc

import random

def very_heavy_operation():
    return str(random.randint(0, 10))

def main():
    process_btn_ph = st.empty()
    process_btn = process_btn_ph.button('process', disabled=False, key='1')
    text_wait = st.empty()

    print(process_btn) # for debug

    if 'process_btn_state' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.process_btn_state = False

    if process_btn or st.session_state.process_btn_state:
        st.session_state.process_btn_state = True

        process_btn_ph.button('process', disabled=True, key='2')
        text_wait.markdown('**processing...**')
        result = very_heavy_operation()

        stc.html(f'<div>{result}</div>', height=100, scrolling=True)

        process_btn_ph.button('process', disabled=False, key='3')
        text_wait.empty()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```