# Prevent page refresh in streamlit

Tags: streamlit

In my streamlit app, I use a form for the user to input some filters (date-range etc). On submit, a visualization is shown with a download-button below to download a CSV of the shown data

Something like (pseudo-code)

```
with st.form(key="input_parameters"):
    choices = st.multiselect(...) 
    .... more inputs here
    submitted = st.form_submit_button("Submit")

if submitted:
   data = get_data(choices,...)
   st.linechart(data)
   st.download_button("Download CSV",data)
```

my problem is that after the user clicked the download_button, the page reloads and the graphics disappears. How can I solve that? Is there a way to resubmit the form with the same input again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [st.file\_uploader returns None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74518601/st-file-uploader-returns-none)

Comment: see also https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/4382 and https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/why-download-button-reload-page/24380

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the script is rerun after the user presses the submit button, resetting `submitted` to `False`.

You can circumvent this behaviour by adding a flag to the session state and check if it was previously set. Maybe there are more elegant ways of doing this, but this is one way:

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dummy_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 2)), columns=['X', 'Y'])
try:
    # check if the key exists in session state
    _ = st.session_state.keep_graphics
except AttributeError:
    # otherwise set it to false
    st.session_state.keep_graphics = False

with st.form(key="input_parameters"):
    choices = st.multiselect('Choose me', ['Plot1', 'Plot2'])
    submitted = st.form_submit_button("Submit")

if submitted or st.session_state.keep_graphics:
    st.line_chart(dummy_data)
    st.session_state.keep_graphics = True
    st.download_button("Download CSV", dummy_data.to_csv())
```

Answer (score 2):

This workaround did it for me. Use a markdown with a HTML download button instead. I did it for an image, You will have to convert your .csv to bytes.

```
# Create a custom download button using HTML and JavaScript
result = io.BytesIO()
output_image.save(result, format='PNG')
result.seek(0)

download_link = f'<a href="data:application/octet-stream;base64, 
                {base64.b64encode(result.read()).decode()}" download=" 
                {filename}.png">Download Image</a>'
st.markdown(download_link, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

[streamlit-ext](https://pypi.org/project/streamlit-ext/) did the trick:

```
import streamlit_ext as ste
ste.download_button(...)
```

Comment: AFAIK its not in your linked "official" streamlit-extras, but in https://github.com/PaleNeutron/streamlit-ext

Comment: Exactly, @RaphaelRoth. I've edited my reply to the correct link of streamit-ext as you mentioned. Thanks