# Streamlit nested button not displaying the result on clicking

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

I have a small code which accepts .txt files and process it and returns statement saying that process completed

Also, another button which on click should show the output folder path.
Strangely this is not working. Here is my code.

```
import streamlit as st

def main():
    st.title(":blue[Keyword Replacement] :twisted_rightwards_arrows:")
    activity1 = ["Keyword Replacement"]
    choice = st.sidebar.selectbox("What do you want to do?",activity1)
    if choice == 'Keyword Replacement':
        st.subheader("Please upload the file")
        uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload file", type={"txt"})
        if uploaded_file is not None:
            if st.button("Submit"):
                st.write("Process completed")
                output_path = r"C:\Users\Myname\directory"
                if st.button('Show output folder path'):
                    st.markdown(f"**Outpul folder is located at:**  {output_path}")    ## NOT WORKING
                    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the screenshot of the app, the highlighted yellow button should print the output path after clicking, but nothing happens.
[image]

Am I missing something here.

I came across session state but couldn't understand it. Is it because of that I'm not able to get the desired output on clicking the nested button.

Any leads would be helpful

Comment: Streamlit flow can be tricky specially if you have a nested button. Read the [button behavior](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/button-behavior-and-examples) to be successful in using a button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [st.file\_uploader returns None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74518601/st-file-uploader-returns-none)